# Add number of occurrences for each element of a character vector

Tags: r, replace

Assuming we have

```
sig <- c("In neither", "In neither", "In both", 
         "T1 vs Ta", "T1 vs Ta",   "T1 vs Ta",  
         "T2 vs T1", "T2 vs T1", "T2 vs T1",  "T2 vs T1")
```

how could someone obtain the following two?

```
sig.size <- c("In neither (n = 2)", "In neither (n = 2)", "In both (n = 1)"
          "T1 vs Ta (n = 3)", "T1 vs Ta (n = 3)", "T1 vs Ta (n = 3)",  
          "T2 vs T1 (n = 4)", "T2 vs T1 (n = 4)", "T2 vs T1 (n = 4)",  "T2 vs T1 (n = 4)")

sig.fac <- c("T1 vs Ta (n = 3)", "T2 vs T1 (n = 4)", "In both (n = 1)", "In neither (n = 2)")
```

This is an excerpt of the data, since the vector `sig` contains more than 10k elements. I tried
using `table(sig)` and a double `for` loop in combination with `gsub` and `paste0` but wasn't able to get anything. The thing is that I would like to pass this automation in a function
that generates scatterplots. For consistency reasons, I need `sig.fac` to have this specific ordering, so as to define factor levels before doing the ggplot. e.g. with:

```
df$sig <- factor(df$sig, levels=sig.fac)
```

Thanks in advance for the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
sig <- c("In neither", "In neither", "In both", 
         "T1 vs Ta", "T1 vs Ta",   "T1 vs Ta",  
         "T2 vs T1", "T2 vs T1", "T2 vs T1",  "T2 vs T1")
sig.tbl <- table(sig)
sprintf("%s (n = %s)", sig, sig.tbl[sig])
#  [1] "In neither (n = 2)" "In neither (n = 2)" "In both (n = 1)"    "T1 vs Ta (n = 3)"   "T1 vs Ta (n = 3)"  
#  [6] "T1 vs Ta (n = 3)"   "T2 vs T1 (n = 4)"   "T2 vs T1 (n = 4)"   "T2 vs T1 (n = 4)"   "T2 vs T1 (n = 4)"  
sprintf("%s (n = %s)", names(sig.tbl), sig.tbl)
# [1] "In both (n = 1)"    "In neither (n = 2)" "T1 vs Ta (n = 3)"   "T2 vs T1 (n = 4)"
```

Order can be handled many ways, here's one:

```r
sig.tbl <- sig.tbl[match(names(sig.tbl), c("T1 vs Ta", "T2 vs T1", "In both", "In neither"))]
sprintf("%s (n = %s)", names(sig.tbl), sig.tbl)
# [1] "T1 vs Ta (n = 3)"   "T2 vs T1 (n = 4)"   "In both (n = 1)"    "In neither (n = 2)"
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, using a tidy approach

```
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
library(glue)
df = tibble(sig = sig) %>% count(sig) %>% mutate(var = glue('{sig} (n = {n})'))
 unique(df$var)

[1] "In both (n = 1)"    "In neither (n = 2)" "T1 vs Ta (n = 3)"   "T2 vs T1 (n = 4)"
```

Answer (score 1):

We could use `paste` for this problem

```
paste0(names(sig.tbl), " (n= ", sig.tbl, ")")
#[1] "In both (n= 1)"    "In neither (n= 2)" "T1 vs Ta (n= 3)" 
#[4] "T2 vs T1 (n= 4)"
```

Or `stack` the `table` to a two column dataset and `paste`

```
with(stack(sig.tbl), paste0(ind, " (n = ", values, ")"))
```

#### data

```
sig <- c("In neither", "In neither", "In both", 
         "T1 vs Ta", "T1 vs Ta",   "T1 vs Ta",  
         "T2 vs T1", "T2 vs T1", "T2 vs T1",  "T2 vs T1")
sig.tbl <- table(sig)
```